# ORDER BY IF statement in MYSQL, if result is less than

Tags: mysql

I have a table that looks somewhat like this ordered by `received_date DESC`

```
+---------+---------------+------------+---------------+
|  name   |  assignment   |  due_date  | received_date |
+---------+---------------+------------+---------------+
| Luke    | Vacuum        | 2018-06-14 | 2018-01-04    |
| Mark    | Wash the car  | 2016-01-01 | 2018-01-03    |
| Matthew | Do the dishes | NULL       | 2018-01-02    |
| John    | Walk the dog  | 2019-01-01 | 2018-01-01    |
+---------+---------------+------------+---------------+
```

I'm trying to return rows by `due_date` but only if the `due_date` was in the past or is tomorrow, otherwise keep it ordered by the `received_date`. For example, I'd like the above table to end up as

```
+---------+---------------+------------+---------------+
|  name   |  assignment   |  due_date  | received_date |
+---------+---------------+------------+---------------+
| Mark    | Wash the car  | 2016-01-01 | 2018-01-03    | due_date in the past
| Luke    | Vacuum        | 2018-06-14 | 2018-01-04    | due_date tomorrow
| Matthew | Do the dishes | NULL       | 2018-01-02    | rest sorted by received_date DESC
| John    | Walk the dog  | 2019-01-01 | 2018-01-01    |
+---------+---------------+------------+---------------+
```

First I tried

```
SELECT *, DATEDIFF(due_date,CURDATE()) AS due 
FROM table 
ORDER BY IF(due < 2, due_date, received_date) DESC, received_date DESC
```

But this doesn't work for negative numbers, so I tried turning the negatives into a zero:

```
SELECT *, IF(DATEDIFF(due_date,CURDATE()) > 0, DATEDIFF(due_date,CURDATE()), 0) AS due  
FROM table 
ORDER BY IF(due < 2, due_date, received_date) DESC, received_date DESC
```

But any positive number between `due_date` and now (like John's) is added to the top of the list, and ends up looking like

```
+---------+---------------+------------+---------------+
|  name   |  assignment   |  due_date  | received_date |
+---------+---------------+------------+---------------+
| John    | Walk the dog  | 2019-01-01 | 2018-01-01    |
| Mark    | Wash the car  | 2016-01-01 | 2018-01-03    |
| Luke    | Vacuum        | 2018-06-14 | 2018-01-04    |
| Matthew | Do the dishes | NULL       | 2018-01-02    |
+---------+---------------+------------+---------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this logic:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(due_date, CURDATE()) <= 1
         THEN due_date
         ELSE received_date END;
```

However, I get a different output than what you expect:

[image]

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT *, IF(DATEDIFF(due_date, CURDATE()) > 0, 1, IF(DATEDIFF(due_date, CURDATE()) < 0, -1, 0)) as tmp_col FROM `to_do` order by tmp_col asc, `received_date` desc;
```